# Find the top three free apps based off chosen column in python

Tags: python, pandas

I want to write a function that finds the top three Free apps based on 'Reviews', 'Rating', 'Installs'.

It should return a data frame that has the category and app for the first two columns, and one of Rating, Installs, and Reviews as the third column

right now my code looks like this:

input:

```
def topthree(column):
    Googleapps_df["Reviews"] = pd.to_numeric(Googleapps_df["Reviews"])
    Googleapps_df["Installs"] = pd.to_numeric(Googleapps_df["Installs"])
    Googleapps_df["Rating"] = pd.to_numeric(Googleapps_df["Rating"])
    topthree = Googleapps_df.groupby('Type')[column].nlargest(3)
    return topthree

topthree('Reviews')
```

output:

```
Type      
Free  1879    44893888.0
      1670    44891723.0
      1704    44891723.0
Paid  4034      408292.0
      7417      348962.0
      8860      190086.0
Name: Reviews, dtype: float64
```

How do I add an app column in between the type and numbers, and how do I get rid of the 3 Paid number so it looks like this:

```
Type      App
    Free  "App_name"   1879    44893888.0
          "App_name"   1670    44891723.0
          "App_name"   1704    44891723.0
    Name: Reviews, dtype: float64
```

Answer (score 0):

As you do not need the second type first filter that then find the max value of each of the three columns. Use:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'name':['a','b','c','d','f','g','h','i'],'type':[1,2,2,1,1,1,2,2],'reviews':[500,4,350,102,35,40,4,350],'ratings':[8,45,822,23,74,100,4,350],'installs':[4,5,6,7,81,1,4,350]})
df1=df[df['type']==1]
n1 = df1[(df1['reviews']==df1['reviews'].max())]['name'].values[0]
n2 = df1[(df1['ratings']==df1['ratings'].max())]['name'].values[0]
n3 = df1[(df1['installs']==df1['installs'].max())]['name'].values[0]
out = pd.DataFrame({'name': [n1,n2,n3], 'values': vals})
```

Input:

[image]

Output:

[image]

Comment: is df1 the same as df? @keramat

Comment: Sorry, please check the answer again.

Comment: That works now?

Comment: I am getting this error when I run it "array length 3 does not match index length 0"

Comment: Which line produces the error?

Comment: It occurs on the out = pd.DataFrame({'name': df1['name'], 'values': vals}) line. Also i mistyped the error is "array length 3 does not match index length 9059"

Comment: So, check if the df1 and vales has the same length? I suspect that there are some common app that appears top in more than one cols.

Comment: Edited the answer.

Comment: I figured out the issue. Thank you so much for you help!

Comment: You're welcome, please tick the answer as accepted.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a filter to only show your results of where Type == 'Free' either after the `.groupby('Type')` or when you call the function.

Additionally, you can append your table with `Googleapps_df['App']` since currently you are just showing the grouby tree that you have with Type and column.

Answer (score 0):

Change:

```
topthree = Googleapps_df.groupby('Type')[column].nlargest(3)
```

to [`GroupBy.head`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.head.html) with sorting by both columns by [`DataFrame.sort_values`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sort_values.html):

```
(topthree = Googleapps_df.sort_values(['Type',column], ascending=True, False)
                         .groupby('Type')[column]
                         .head(3))
```

Or convert column `App` to index:

```
(topthree = Googleapps_df.set_index('App')
                         .groupby('Type')[column]
                         .nlargest(3))
```

If need `Series` from first solution set it after `groupby.head`:

```
topthree = (Googleapps_df.sort_values(['Type',column], ascending=True, False)
                         .groupby('Type')[column]
                         .head(3)
                         .set_index(['Type', 'App'])[column])
```

Comment: Hi converting the app to index worked!

Comment: @Axe - Super! Glad can help!